# How to let clients set up their personalized demos

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, iis-7, configuration

I have developed a web application and I would like to give my clients set up their personalized demos from the product's website directly. For example for my product "`SchedulingApp`", a client '`John`' may be able to create his own link like `john.demos.schedulingapp.com`.

I have no idea how it would be done in IIS.

Do I need to create separate applications dynamically in IIS for each demo?
How do I attach the client prefix in the demo URL?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check this here  have created website in iss programatically with one soucre code
your client have to enter the hostname,websitname

[Click to view code](http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-new-website-on-iis.html)

http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-new-website-on-iis.html